# How to change the appearance of another class when hovering on an img?

Tags: html, css

I’m currently trying to build my website with only a basic knowledge of HTML / CSS.

http://www.ufo.studio

I’m trying to set up the CSS so that when the user hovers over the main case study images on the home page the  and  display with an underline.

Here is a section of the HTML for one block on the home page:

—

```
<div class="asos_content">
<a href="/projects/asos_creates.html">  
       <img src="img/home/ASOS_home.gif" class ="wow animated fadeInUp imgroll">

           <title class="wow animated fadeIn">ASOS Agency Brand Identity</title>

          <tags class="wow animated fadeIn">Strategy, Art Direction & Design</tags>
</a>
</div class="asos_content">
```

—

Ideally if the user hovers over the img then the underlines will appear under the title and tag at the same time too.

Is this possible using CSS? Any help greatly appreciated..

thanks so much.
Ben

Comment: You don't close div containers the way you are doing it, you just write </div>, that's it.

Answer (score 3):

You use the `:hover` pseudo-selector on the surrounding `a` element then select the appropriate children and apply the appropriate properties.

For example:

```
.asos_content a:hover title,
.asos_content a:hover tags
{
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Note that `title` and `tags` are not standard HTML elements. They are probably better represented as `h1` and `h2` or some other heading element.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot using "hover." You can get more info on how this works here if you would like: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

HTML:

```
 <span class="wow">Some Text That will be underlined when you hover</span>
```

CSS:

```
    .wow:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wgny00xo/

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to do isn't really feasible with CSS, because styles only cascade down nested tags.

What you can do is add a quick snippet of javascript to achieve the same result you're looking for.

```js
function onRoll() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].style.textDecoration = 'underline';
  document.getElementsByTagName("h2")[0].style.textDecoration = 'underline';
}
```

```css
h1 {
  text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="asos_content">
  <a href="/projects/asos_creates.html">
    <img src="img/home/ASOS_home.gif" onmouseover="onRoll()" class="wow animated fadeInUp imgroll"/>

    <h1 class="wow animated fadeIn">ASOS Agency Brand Identity</h1>

    <h2 class="wow animated fadeIn">Strategy, Art Direction &amp; Design</h2>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, it is very feasible to do in CSS with sibling selectors `+` and `~`, i.e. `img:hover + h1, img:hover + h1 + h2`. I simply didn't add that to my answer because it makes more sense to apply the hover to the parent `a` element.